# How write data to ADLS in Synapse using Spark R

Tags: r, dataframe, azure-synapse

I have an issue that I'm not able to figure out myself. I run R script in Synapse Spark and I need to store the outcome of that script into CSV file in ADLS.

I have tested reading a CSV file and trying to write that back into separate CSV file but it seems to not working.

I use this logic to read the CSV file:

```
dfcsv1 <- read.df('abfs://[my-container]@[my-storage-account].dfs.core.windows.net/test/testdata2.csv', 'csv', header="true")
```

Change to data frame

```
df <- as.data.frame(dfcsv1)
```

And with this I try to write it back:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").csv("abfs://[my-container]@[my-storage-account].dfs.core.windows.net/test//testdata3.csv")
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error: [1] "Error in base::parse(...): :1:27: unexpected symbol\n1: df.write.mode("overwrite").csv\n                              ^"

What I need to do to fix this?

Comment: ADLS I suspect.

Comment: I think it is ADLS (Azure Data lake gen2) only

Comment: Yes, Azure data lake gen2.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates that there is a syntax error in your code. The  `df.write.mode("overwrite").csv()`  function call is not valid R syntax.

To write a dataframe to a CSV file in ADLS using SparkR, you can use the  `write.df()`  function. Below is the code:

```
# Write the data frame to a new CSV file in ADLS
write.df(dfcsv1, path="abfss://[my-container]@[my-storage-account].dfs.core.windows.net/test/testdata3.csv", source="csv", mode = "overwrite")
```

[image]

When this code is executed for writing data to ADLS, data is written successfully without any error.

**Reference:** [SparkR (R on Spark) - Spark 3.5.0 Documentation (apache.org)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#from-data-sources)

Comment: Thank you! This worked. You saved my day.